# What's fastest way for calculate this Sigma?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Sorry for bad English.
What's the fastest way to calculate this?

$$
\sum_{i=11}^{35}\left(\begin{array}{c}
35 \\
i
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{i}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{35-i}=0.0004
$$

Is the solution for this related to the Central limit theorem? If is it, how to solve with this theorem ? 
Thank You.

Comment: i you have a calculator then write a littel program

Comment: approximate the binomial distribution with the normal using the CLT

Comment: Ask Wolfram Alpha. Many other programs will do it. Using the normal approximation makes me a little nervous, $n=35$ is smallish, and $p=1/10$ yields a quite skewed distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the quickest way was with a computer.

For example in R

`m <- 35; n <- 11:m; sum(choose(m,n) * 0.1^n * 0.9^(m-n))`

gives `0.0004242976`.

If you wanted to do this approximately by hand, it seems likely that  *most* of the sum is in the $i=11$ term, which is about $0.0003328$. The $n=12$ term is about $0.000073957$ and the others are rather smaller.

If you were to use the Central Limit Theorem then you have a binomial distribution with mean $35\times0.1 = 3.5$ and variance $35\times0.1 \times0.9 = 3.15$.  So with a continuity correction, you want the probability that a  standard normal distribution is greater than $\frac{10.5-3.5}{\sqrt{3.15}} \approx 3.944053$  giving $0.000040058$, which is wrong by more than a factor of $10$.  You should not expect the Central Limit Theorem to give accurate answers in the tail.